# Use glossary group headings as sections/chapters/etc

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, glossaries-extra

I'm trying to make a little Spanish dictionary with the package `glossaries`. I've tried to redefine group headings as sections. This is a MWE (`polyglossia` seems to be necessary, as there's no PDF ouptput when I omit it):

```latex
%!TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{spanish}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[automake,style=long,xindy={language={spanish-modern}}]{glossaries-extra}
\newcommand{\entrada}[4][]{%
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{%
        \section{\glsgetgrouptitle{##1}}
    }
    \newglossaryentry{#2}%
    {%
        name=#2,%
        symbol=#3,%
        description=#4,%
        #1%
    }%
    \glsadd{#2}%
}
\newglossarystyle{entrada}%
{%
    \renewenvironment*{theglossary}{}{}
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%
        \par\vspace{0.25\baselineskip}%
        \noindent{}##4\textbf{##2.} {##3}%
    }%
}%
\makeglossaries
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \entrada{Pollo}{}{Ave}
    \entrada{Carne}{}{Parte blanda de los animales}
    \entrada{Cosa}{}{Objeto de}
    \printglossary[style=entrada]
\end{document}
```

What I get is the following problem lines

```
Undefined control sequence. \glsgroupheading{C}
Undefined control sequence. \glsgroupheading{P}
```

Moreover, TOC shows numbers instead of actual sections:
[image]

I've also tried using unnumbered sections by manually adding them to TOC via `\addcontentsline`, unsuccessfully.
Is there some way to fix these errors?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you please make your code an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) (with emphasis on _minimal_)? Are any of the packages other than `glossaries` necessary? Not everyone has the same fonts you have, so it's best to just use the default font if your issue is not font related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is using `\glsgetgrouptitle` in the argument of `\section`, because this is a so-called moving argument, i.e. it will get executed at different places in the document. Since `\glsgetgrouptitle` is not expandable and does not work anywhere in the document, this cannot work.

Since in your example `\glsgetgrouptitle` doesn't actually do anything, you can just leave it out. Note that you should redefine `\glsgroupheading` in the glossary style and not in `\entrada`.

```
%!TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{spanish}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[automake,style=long,xindy={language={spanish-modern}}]{glossaries-extra}
\makeglossaries

\newcommand{\entrada}[4][]{%
  \newglossaryentry{#2}%
  {%
    name=#2,%
    symbol=#3,%
    description=#4,%
    #1%
  }%
  \glsadd{#2}%
}
\newglossarystyle{entrada}%
  {%
    \renewenvironment*{theglossary}{}{}%
    \renewcommand*\glossaryheader{}%
    \renewcommand*\glsgroupheading[1]{%
      \section{##1}%
    }%
    \renewcommand*\glsgroupskip{}%
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%
      \par\vspace{0.25\baselineskip}%
      \noindent{}##4\textbf{##2.} {##3}%
    }%
  }%

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\entrada{Pollo}{}{Ave}
\entrada{Carne}{}{Parte blanda de los animales}
\entrada{Cosa}{}{Objeto de}
\printglossary[style=entrada]

\end{document}
```